# equation with series

Tags: problem-solving

Hello to everybody I have a problem because I can't solve this equation:

$$960 - \frac{84.60}{(1+x)^{\frac1{12}}} - \frac{84.60}{(1+x)^{\frac2{12}}} - \cdots - \frac{84.60}{(1+x)^{\frac{11}{12}}} - \frac{84.60}{(1+x)^{\frac{12}{12}}} = 0$$

I haven't any idea about the approach to use in order to obtain "$x$".

Everybody can help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what `84,60` means?  And does e.g. `60/(1+x)^1/12` mean $\frac{60}{(1+x)^{1/12}}$?

Comment: What you call "equation" is really unclear. Use some LaTeX to write mathematics and clear that up.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new here. Yes Rebecca it means exactly what you have indicated

Comment: You still haven't explained what that odd 84 there means, @Owl...and new or not: read a little before posting to learn how to properly do it.

Comment: I'll read rules as soon as possible. 84.60 are rates of a loan and the unknown x is the TAEG. I have to found the value of x. But I don't know how. Can I use Taylor series in order to simplify the denominator?

Comment: @Owl: I have attempted to clean up the formatting so that the question is understandable. Please be certain that my edits are true to the intention of your post.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Cameron Buie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $(1+x)^{1/12}$ as $u$ to save typing, so your equation would be
$$\begin{align}
960&=84.6\left(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{u^{12}}\right)\\
   &=84.6\left(1+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{u^{12}}\right)-84.6
\end{align}$$
The reason I added and subtracted $84.6$ on the right was that the parenthesized expression is now a familiar geometric series with value
$$
1+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{u^{12}}=\frac{1-(1/u)^{13}}{1-(1/u)}=\frac{u-(1/u)^{12}}{u-1}
$$
so your equation is now (after a trifling bit of algebra)
$$
\frac{1044.6}{84.6}=\frac{u-(1/u)^{12}}{u-1}
$$
or
$$
960u^{13}-1044.6u^{12}+84.6=0
$$
This has an obvious solution $u=1$ and for the rest you might have to use approximation methods or, what amounts to the same thing, a computer algebra system.

**Update**. Mathematica tells me there are three real solutions: $u=-0.775465, 1, 1.00871$, corresponding to $x=-0.952712, 0, 0.1096752$, respectively.

Comment: You might try solver in excel or similar spreadsheet.